# Unable to interpret control operator in linux

Tags: c, linux, unix, gcc, terminal

I have the following C program saved in a file named 1.c

```
#include<stdio.h> 
void main() 
{ 
printf("Hello World");
}
```

After compiling it, I try to execute it using

```
./a.out || echo Hi
```

I expect to see the following output

```
Hello World
```

But the output that I get is

```
Hello WorldHi
```

The above output seems to be wrong since `echo hi` should execute only if `./a.out` does not get executed successfully. Where am I wrong in interpreting the output?

Comment: Your main does not have a return. "Successful execution" is signaled by a program to the shell using its return value. Add a return 0 and it should work as you intend. (EDIT: Of course, also add proper return type to the function)

Comment: In addition, write your main as `int main() { ...  return 0; }` so it is syntactically able to return a value.

Comment: Try using the correct type for the `main` function, that is it should be `int` not `void`, and include a `return 0;` at the end of the function so that it will inform the system that it executed successfully.

Answer (score 2):

Your application must return a value:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main(void) 
{ 
    printf("Hello World\n");
    return 0;
}
```

---

Always compile your code with `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`, that would stop your original code from compiling because `void main()` is not a valid [entry point](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function).

Comment: Okay but I am designing for user interaction. And I don't want to force the user to use int main() instead of void main (). Is there any way to run the right side of || only if void main () does not exist properly?

Comment: @shivamag00 `void main()` is just wrong, and that has nothing to do with user interaction. The only two variants of `main` which are defined in the C standard are `int main(void)` and `int main(int argc, char* argv[])` and as you can see, in both cases `main` has the return type `int`. (you are however free to create your own compiler, which could generate whatever output you want when compiling `void main()`)

Comment: Gcc compiles void main()

Comment: @shivamag00 Yes it does (unless you compile with `-pedantic` i guess), but a compiler isn't required to output a warning or error when it encounters undefined behavior. It can do pretty much whatever it wants, and in your case the result obviously doesn't match your expectations. You want to **use** the return value of `main` in a shell script, so you have to **provide** a return value in `main`, it's as simple as that.

Answer (score 2):

The `void main()` is invoking undefined behavior of your program. From [C11 standard 5.1.2.2.1p1](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1p1) the correct `main` signature is:

- `int main(void) { /* ... */ }`
- `int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* .. */ }`
- any equivalent to the two above
- or some implementation-defined `main`.

You [compiler](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Implementation.html) doesn't has any implementation-defined `main` and `void main()` is not equivalent to any other two forms.

So undefined behavior of your program manifests itself by your program exiting with nonzero exit status which causes the shell the execute the right side of `||`. Change the return value of `main` to `int`.

Comment: Okay but I am designing for user interaction. And I don't want to force the user to use int main() instead of void main (). Is there any way to run the right side of || only if void main () does not exist properly?

Comment: I am sorry, but your comment just doesn't make sense to me. I do not understand. Does user "inputs" the C program? Is you user expected to input a C program? If so, then your user made a mistake - `void main()` is not a valid C statement on your platform. `Is there any way to run...` Just don't use `||`, use `;` if you want to ignore the exit status of the program.

Comment: Yes user is expected to input a c program. I want to echo something only if the user's c code runs incorrectly

Comment: Then define "C code runs correctly". If you define "c code runs correctly" as "C code with no undefined behavior", then such job is just impossible. I do not know of any tool that would allow to diagnose all instances of undefined behavior. Compilers are allowed (and expected to) produce programs that behave unexpectedly in erroneous ways when C code has undefined behavior, there is no running away. Still, it's popular to enable all possible compiler warnings and treat warnings as errors, to catch _most_ erroneous constructs.